# group mysql rows and print data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

lets say i have 10 rows that 5 of them have same id and the other 5 have another same id.

```
id ---------name

55 -------- name1
55 -------- name2
55 -------- name3 
66 -------- name6
66 -------- name7
55 -------- name4
66 -------- name8
66 -------- name9
66 -------- name10
55 -------- name5
```

i wanna select these 10 rows and group by that same id. so i will have 2 groups and i wanna print all data of group 1 then print all data of group 2.

the result would be this :

- group1(name1,name2,name3,name4,name5)
- group2(name6,name7,name8,name9,name10)

  how is it possible?

thanks in advance ...

Comment: first of all: if *multiple datasets* have the *same ID*, something is wrong with your database. second: what have you **tried yourself** so far? third: have you checked the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)?

Comment: I would start by looking at the [MySQL manual - GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann A bold assertion on scant information

Comment: @Strawberry an actual primary key column with duplicate values *definitely* is a big mistake, and any foreign key simply named `id` instead of, for example `tablename_id` is *very poorly named* at best. so, either way, something is amiss.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann An actual primary key column with duplicate values is a contradiction in terms. I agree about the naming policy - but (certain caveats aside) there's not much wrong with a PK formed on (id,name), say.

Answer (score -1):

PDO has many wonderful fetch modes for you. I managed to compile them all in the article from which you can learn that [PDO already group the data](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP) right off the query:

```
$sql = "select id, name from table";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

now you have an array which keys are ids and values are arrays with names. Here is a simplest example though you can format your output as you wish

```
foreach ($data as $id => $names) {
    echo "$id (".implode(",", $names).")";
}
```

this solution is way more flexible than SQL-based one. Say if you want to put each name in a distinct table cell of whatever.